# Getting identifier of custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

i have 2 custom cell which singleCell and doubleCell. I want to know which one selected when didSelectItemAt method trigered.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if singleSelected {
        print("SINGLE CELL SELECTED)
    } else {
        print("DOUBLE CELL SELECTED)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the `cellForItem` in your `didSelectItemAt` function:

```
if let singleCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? SingleCell {
    // singleCell selected
} else {
    // doubleCell selected
}
```

Comment: @Brkr, great! Glad to help.